# Issue with button icons while running in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I am developing a rails 3.2.13 app with jQuery Mobile and using the jquery_mobile_rails gem which means I don't need to install any of the jQuery files. My problem is that there are no icons for the buttons. These are displayed in development but not in production. I assume that I just need to compile them but where are they and how can I do that?

Since I am not using jQuery Mobile files directly, I don't have the option to store the icons below them. The gem works in development mode but not in production mode. Can I assume that the gems contain the button icons internally? If so, I am at a loss to understand why they don't work in production mode.

```
jquery-rails (3.0.4, 3.0.2)
jquery_mobile_rails (1.3.2)
```

These are the versions of the gem i'm using, can anyone please help me out!!! Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4.0.0 jQuery Mobile button icons not showing in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383506/rails-4-0-0-jquery-mobile-button-icons-not-showing-in-production)

Comment: @Omar  Thanks but I have tried with that solution but nothing happend for me

Comment: I have added relevant tags to get more attention. You'll be assisted soon.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.....its working fine when i give

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">

in my application.html